# Excel gives error when saving macro enabled file

Tags: excel, vba, filtering

I'm very new to vba and a lot of the below code was found online.

```
Option Compare Text

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rngCell     As Range
    Dim rngRange    As Range
    Dim strLookFor  As String
    Dim arrChar     As Variant
    Dim lngCounter  As Long
    
    
    Set activeTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")
    
   
    activeTable.Range.AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:="*" & [J3] & "*", Operator:=xlFilterValues
    Set rRng = ActiveSheet.Range("J3")
    
    If IsEmpty(rRng.Value) Then
        activeTable.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        activeTable.ListColumns(10).Range.Font.Color = vbBlack
    Else
        Call Highlight_words
    End If
    
End Sub


Private Sub Highlight_words()
    
    
    Set rngRange = Range("J7:J" & Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    rngRange.Font.Color = vbBlue
    strLookFor = Range("J3").Value
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    For Each rngCell In rngRange
        For lngCounter = 1 To Len(rngCell) - Len(strLookFor) + 1
            If Mid(rngCell, lngCounter, Len(strLookFor)) = strLookFor Then
                rngCell.Characters(lngCounter, Len(strLookFor)).Font.Color = vbRed
            End If
        Next lngCounter
    Next rngCell

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
End Sub
```

While the code seems to work in my worksheet, every time I try to save it in "desktop>filename"(as XLSM file) it gives me the following error:

*Errors were detected while saving 'file name'. Microsoft excel may be able to save the file by removing or repairing some features. To make the repairs in a new file, click Continue. To cancel saving the file, click Cancel.*

I noticed that it only gives me the error if I unhide the for loop. So I'm wondering what's wrong with the for loop?

Comment: @braX I understand that the OP does not want to save the file with the macro, just wants to save the file where the macro happens to be and then gets the error - Rabbit please confirm.

Comment: @braX, Thanks, what do you mean with this? I added activeworkbook.save, but that didn't work.

Comment: @DávidLaczkó, yes indeed. I get the error upon saving and then with the method of elimination it seems the for loop is the problem. But I don't see why. The code works untill I have to save it. Then I get the error.

Comment: Could you do in the VB editor: Debug -> Compile VBAProject, and re-try saving

Comment: If the workbook has code in it, you have to save it using the correct file type too. You cannot save it with just a name. Where is your attempt to save it? Please include that in your question. It has to be an XLSM file, not a XLSX file.

Comment: @ Dávid I tried that, and that also doesn't work. Same error.

Comment: @BraX. Yes, I saved it as XLSM and It still have that error.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean? To save the file I close the VB editor and click on file -> save as -> save as xlsm and then I get the error. And I save it locally on my desktop.

Comment: Sounds like a corrupt file to me.  Have you tried copying the code into a new file, recreating your sheets and trying again?  I'd also suggest going into Tools ~ Options in the Visual Basic Editor and ticking _Require Variable Declaration_.  That shouldn't be related to the problem, but will point out you haven't declared `rRng`, `activetable`, `RngRange`, `strLookFor`, `rngCell` and `lngCounter`.

Comment: @ Darren, Yes I've copied the worksheet in a new excel file and copied the code in there. I've done all that you said, but I still get the error when I try to save as an XLSM file. I tried to save it as an XLSB file. I don't know if that's ok. Saving it like that works, but now when I open this file it asks me to repair and I did and then it says: *Repaired records: string properties from /xl/sharedstrings.bin part (strings). * What does that mean and is it ok to save it like this?

Comment: When you have a corrupt file, it's often better to not copy the worksheet itself, recreate it instead

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Excel (blank file)
2. File > Open
3. Navigate to file
4. Use arrow next to 'Open' button
5. Open and repair

Answer (score 0):

When attempting to save the file in an XLSM format, you may be seeing an error due to the VBA code or how it interacts with Excel features.

From what I can understand from your code, here are some points that I want to highlight.

1. Make sure that the length that Len(strLookFor) returns is not longer than the value of rngCell. Should it occur, an out-of-bounds error might result.
2. This nested loop process may use a lot of memory and CPU power, depending on the size of rngRange. Excel may experience resource constraints if rngRange spans a wide range of cells, which could result in save problems.
3. To capture any potential mistakes that might arise during the loop iteration, add error handling techniques.
4. Verify whether your workbook's VBA code and any unique features are compatible with the XLSM file format.

Here are some references I found on google-
https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/ld6hye/learn_to_fix_errors_were_detected_while_saving/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/53015/microsoft-should-fix-errors-were-detected-while-sa?source=docs